# Print row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I print my dataframe, `total`, this is printed:

```
               TimeTaken
StartLocation           
?                 3430.0
bathroom         17144.0
...                  ...
```

I want a series of the locations, like so:

```
? 
bathroom
...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That looks like the index. `total.index`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983450/psidom). It can be done by using:

```
total.index
```